# Elasticsearch Regex to match url starting with one string and not ending with another, without look ahead/behind

Tags: regex, url, elasticsearch

I have two groups of strings that take the formats

```
http://example.com/foo/something
```

and

```
http://example.com/foo/something/something-else/bar/1
```

Where example.com, foo and bar are fixed, something and something else could be any string and 1 is any number.

I want to use regex to match strings following the first format (they must start with `http://example.com/foo/`) and not the second. The exclusion could be around number of slashes, the "bar" string or ending in a number.

I don't have support for look ahead or look back.

What's the best approach?

**Examples of strings that should match**

```
http://example.com/foo/apple
http://example.com/foo/bear-bear
http://example.com/foo/cake-cake
```

**Examples of strings that should NOT match**

```
http://example.com/baa/apple
http://example.com/foo/apple/cake/bar/1
http://example.com/foo/bear-apple/camel/bar/2
```

**Examples of strings that wouldn't exist in the data set**
(So it doesn't matter if they match or not)

```
http://example.com/foo/bear-bear/cake/bar/two
http://example.com/foo/bear/camel/tar/2
http://example.com/foo/bear-bear/camel
http://example.com/foo/bear/camel/
http://example.com/foo/bear-bear/camel/tar/2
```

**UPDATE**

It turns out that the regex engine the application I'm using this in is from Elasticsearch, so this documentation (and one of our developers) was helpful: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-regexp-query.html

The end solution was:

```
(http://example.com/foo.*)&~(.*bar.*)
```

Comment: Can you add a set of samples with a match/not match examples, please?

Comment: @JorgeCampos done. Thanks!

Comment: Would that solve your problem? https://regex101.com/r/wU7rI9/1 Let me know So I will add as an answer if Yes!

Comment: In case you want to match the ending `....foo/` with the slash ending: https://regex101.com/r/wU7rI9/2

Comment: @JorgeCampos in the real world example some strings have "-" in them. I updated the example strings.

Comment: I think that it is ok now! Take a look please: https://regex101.com/r/wU7rI9/3

Answer (score 0):

All your examples have a specific prefix URL, followed by one-and-only-one path element.  If this is the general case, you can do this by simply looking for the prefix URL followed by a word which doesn't contain a path separator, followed by EOL.

You didn't say what engine you're using, so here's an example with Gnu grep in bash:

grep -e '^http://example.com/foo/[^/]\+$'

Bash makes for readable examples, because single-quoting means very few characters need escaping.  The sole exception in my example is the + character.